# Json_Encode with Html String in Twig

Tags: html, json, symfony, twig

I have problem with parsing HTML strings using json_encode. For example my string:

```
<h5>Name</h5>
```

In return my json is ruined because of ">". I found solution in PHP:

```
json_encode('ARRAY', 'JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_TAG')
```

But I need to do it in TWIG and it doesn't work there like that. I've got error:

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Warning: json_encode() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given") in src/Cloud/ApplicationBundle/Resources/views/Filters/tab.html.twig at line 1.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This solution work fine for me:

```
{{ '<h5>Name</h5>'|json_encode(constant('JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES')) }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
 {{ '<h5>Name</h5>'|json_encode(constant('JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_TAG')) }}
```